# MVC4 sending model propert id to controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to send id of a model property  Name to Controller class in an MVC4 application

```
  public class{
public Name{get;set;}
}
```

For Accesing name using id of that property
Update:
Here if change Name using jquery at runtime i want to send the changed name id to the controller class

UPDate:
This is my VIew

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $('.editor input').blur(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('p').find('label').html($(this).val()).show();

    });

    $('.editor label').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('p').find('input').show();

    });

});
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Homepage", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
     <div class="editor">

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, Model.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
       <input type="submit" value="OK"  />
       </p>

     <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Company, Model.Company)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Company)
      <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </p>
     <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.City, Model.City)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.City)
         <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </p>
</div> 
<input type="submit" value="OK"   />
}
```

This is my model

```
 public class Details
{

    public string Name
    { get; set; }


    public string Company
    { get; set; }


    public string City
    { get; set; }


}
```

This is my COntroller methods

```
 public ActionResult Homepage(Details d)
    {
        d.Name = "Rakesh";
        d.Company = "TCS";
        d.City = "DElhi";
        return View(d);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Homepage")]
    public ActionResult Indexof(Details d)
    {
      return View(d);
    }
```

Here i am editing and sending data to the controller but my problem is when i click on Rakesh for example and change the name  then i need to click button  twice then only the changed data is sent to the controller class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model:

```
public class SomeModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction( SomeModel m )
{
    if( ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        // use model
        var name = m.Name;

        return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" );
    }
    return View( m );
}
```

If this isn't what you need, please clarify what's this "id" you're talking about.

Comment: Show me a model with an id of a property.

Comment: Edit your question to elaborate what you are trying to achieve, preferably with sample code for a View, Model and Controller.

Comment: I gave my complete problem in a new question with some code which i worked on        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342871/passing-value-to-controller-in-mvc4-application @Alex